# Scale a bitmap and upload to server, ui thread blocking

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android app where I need to upload an image to a server.

Before I upload the image, I'm scaling it to a max width/height of 500 with Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()

The problem I have is that the UI thread get's stuck even though I do both steps in a background thread.

My code looks like this:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
// upload the image to the server
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bmp = BitmapHelper.scaleBmp(bmp, 500);//bmp is a private class Bitmap
        try {
            HttpResponse response = Helper.uploadBitmap(bmp);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            finalResult = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handleData();
            }
        });
    }
};
t.run();
```

Any help on how to do this correctly would be really appreciated!

EDIT: adding handleData() function

```
public void handleData() {
    take.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    select.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    process.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    select_new.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    message = "An error occured! Please try again.";
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        success = finalResult.getBoolean("success");
        url = "http://url";
        url += finalResult.getString("path");
        thumbnail = finalResult.getString("thumbnail");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    if (success) {
        message = "Picture was uploaded successfuly!";
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
    Config.toast(this, message);

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Bitmap b = HttpHelper.getBitmapFromURL(thumbnail);
            preview_image.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    preview_image.setImageBitmap(b);
                    preview_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    preview_image.setOnClickListener(context);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    t.run();
}
```

Comment: What does handleData do?  Does it do anything on the UI?

Comment: Just added the function to the post. The thing is that it gets stuck even before the dialog is shown (First code snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not starting new threads. You are creating thread objects but you never start new threads. Instead, you just execute the method run in the current thread. For reference how to start a new thread see [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

As @LuxuryMode says, AsyncTask is a very good alternative on Android for long running operations that should not block the ui thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are starting a new `thread` and then inside of it you're using `Handler` to post another `runnable`. So, the `Handler` is associated with this new `Thread` and you cannot manipulate the UI thread from that `thread`. **It seems to me that you really should be using an `AsyncTask`, which provides a convenience for switching from background threads to the UI thread very easily.**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I'll give that a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

aside from what the others posters said, running a thread is done by calling start() not run().